# Different behaviour between Simulator and iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift, datepicker

I'm using [DatePickerCell](https://github.com/DylanVann/DatePickerCell) in my project with 7 date picker cells in a table view controller. I tweaked it so if i click on a new cell, the previously clicked cell date picker would collapse. When i run the app on the Simulator, everything is smooth and works as it's supposed to. When i run the app on my iPhone 5S running iOS 8.3, when i click on a cell, 2 cells expand and other weird things happen as well. What is wrong here ? Using Xcode 8.2.1 Swift 3

Here's the code for the tableview:

```
func dismissPreviousCell()
{
    if previousIndex != nil {
        let cellToDismiss = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: previousIndex!) as? DatePickerCell
        cellToDismiss?.selectedInTableView(tableView)
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

        if let datePickerCell = cell as? DatePickerCell {
            datePickerCell.selectedInTableView(tableView)
            print("Index path is \(indexPath)")
            dismissPreviousCell()
            previousIndex = indexPath
    }
    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code for the TableView

Comment: Check your constraints, is the simulator phone the same size as your phone?

Comment: @Timmy they're the same size. And the constraints shouldn't affect the functionality of the app. On simulator, when cell is clicked, its date picker is expanded. On phone, the next cell's date picker is expanded. And sometimes 2 date pickers are expanded at the same time

Comment: Is your simulator also an "iPhone 5S running iOS 8.3"?  It could be an OS difference.

Comment: Agree with David. If your simulator is running iOS 10.x there could easily be a big difference. Is your XCode project set up to build for iOS 8 ?

Comment: @DavidShaw My simulator is running iOS 10.2. I'm downloading the iOS 8.3 simulator to check. But how it could be an OS difference?

Comment: The Simulator strives to be as accurate as it can be. You are running iOS 10.2 in the Simulator and your device is running iOS 8.3. There have been numerous features, bug fixes, and other changes between the major and minor releases since iOS 8.3.

Comment: There are some simulator bugs involving tapping on a cell, so you may be experiencing one. Test on the device for full accuracy.